# In 12.04 clicking on the launcher icon does not show expo mode for multiple windows

Tags: unity

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit on my machine and something changed recently, and I am not able to bring up the "expo mode" for all windows when clicking on the launcher icon.

When clicking twice on a launcher icon for an application that has multiple windows open, unity should show all the open windows right? Or did that change? Do we need to configure this behavior somewhere?

Comment: If you are only using 1 workspace then this broke in recent unity upgrade - https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/996604

Comment: No, I have not changed the number of workspaces, checked now and its still the default 4.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem since there was a Unity update a few days ago. This is due to Unity 5.12, as 5.10 worked perfectly. This is obviously a pretty serious bug, which can only be solved downgrading to version 5.10 (which I did).